# Java - calculating route distance to arraylist but keeps adding the 3rd element

Tags: java, arraylist

So I'm trying to calculate the distance for each route I have by taking the long and lat. I add this to an arrayList and then move onto the next route. It seems to be calculating the route for the first 3, but then it seems to just keep adding the 3rd element.

Can anyone see what i have done wrong?
It is quite a large function

```
ArrayList<Integer> xCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> yCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int fitness2 = 0;

        for (List<Integer> eachChromeNew : populationShuffle){



            for (int n =0; n < eachChromeNew.size();n++){


                xCoords.add(geoPoints.get(n).getLongitudeE6());
                yCoords.add(geoPoints.get(n).getLatitudeE6());

            }
            for (int c = 0; c < xCoords.size();c++){

                if(c != xCoords.size()-1)
                {

                int x1 = xCoords.get(c);
                int y1 = xCoords.get(c + 1);

                int x2 = yCoords.get(c);
                int y2 = yCoords.get(c + 1);

                fitness2 += Math.sqrt((Math.pow(x2 - x1,2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)));
                }
                fitnessArrayTest.add(fitness2);
            }
            System.out.println("Fitness Test is: = " +fitness2);

        }
```

and this is the output

```
10-08 21:43:10.715: I/System.out(26785): Fitness Test is: = 669448211
10-08 21:43:10.715: I/System.out(26785): Fitness Test is: = 2092025460
10-08 21:43:10.720: I/System.out(26785): Fitness Test is: = 2147483647
10-08 21:43:10.720: I/System.out(26785): Fitness Test is: = 2147483647
10-08 21:43:10.720: I/System.out(26785): Fitness Test is: = 2147483647
10-08 21:43:10.720: I/System.out(26785): Fitness Test is: = 2147483647
```

EDIT

So after changing it to a double like suggested it seems to work slightly but then just seems to increase steadily after a few. Here is what i mean:

1

```
0-08 21:56:07.275: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 6.694724656380861E8
10-08 21:56:07.275: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 2.0921019557100217E9
10-08 21:56:07.275: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 4.267888470215804E9
10-08 21:56:07.275: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 7.196832009155435E9
10-08 21:56:07.280: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 1.0878932572528923E10
10-08 21:56:07.280: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 1.5314190160336267E10
10-08 21:56:07.280: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 2.050260477257744E10
10-08 21:56:07.285: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 2.644417640925244E10
10-08 21:56:07.285: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 3.313890507036129E10
10-08 21:56:07.285: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 4.0586790755903984E10
10-08 21:56:07.285: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 4.878783346588052E10
10-08 21:56:07.285: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 5.774203320029091E10
10-08 21:56:07.285: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 6.744938995913514E10
10-08 21:56:07.285: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 7.790990374241312E10
10-08 21:56:07.290: I/System.out(28729): Fitness Test is: = 8.912357455012492E10
```

What are these E8, E9 and E10 that appear on the end of the numbers?

EDIT

After Martin suggested dividing it by 1000000, i get a better range of answers, however i know come across another, and hopefully the last, problem. This is that the fitness increases everytime and what i am expecting is a random order. Here is the new output

```
10-08 22:18:49.990: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 669.4690141960474
10-08 22:18:49.995: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 2092.0939129186613
10-08 22:18:49.995: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 4267.874696167842
10-08 22:18:49.995: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 7196.8113639435915
10-08 22:18:49.995: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 10878.903916245905
10-08 22:18:50.000: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 15314.152353074784
10-08 22:18:50.005: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 20502.556674430216
10-08 22:18:50.005: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 26444.116880312213
10-08 22:18:50.005: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 33138.83297072078
10-08 22:18:50.005: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 40586.70494565593
10-08 22:18:50.010: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 48787.73280511766
10-08 22:18:50.010: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 57741.916549105954
10-08 22:18:50.010: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 67449.25617762083
10-08 22:18:50.010: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 77909.75169066226
10-08 22:18:50.010: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 89123.40308823026
10-08 22:18:50.010: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 101090.21037032483
10-08 22:18:50.010: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 113810.17353694596
10-08 22:18:50.015: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 127283.29258809367
10-08 22:18:50.015: I/System.out(2576): Fitness Test is: = 141509.56752376774
```

Can anyone now see anything wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `int` for your `fitness2` variable, and you're hitting the upper bounds of what it can handle. Given that you're dealing with large numbers which are inherently floating point, why not use `double` instead?

The effect you're seeing is a curious combination of effects, basically because you're using `+=` on an `int` operator but with a right-hand side which is a `double`. The arithmetic is performed using `double`, but then converted back to `int`, using the rules of [JLS section 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3), which includes this step when the result is too large or small:

> The value must be too large (a positive value of large magnitude or positive infinity), and the result of the first step is the largest representable value of type `int` or `long`.

Comment: @AndrewMurphy: They're the scientific representation of numbers. So 1.23E5 is 123000 for example.

Comment: ahhhh thank you very much @JonSkeet. I have been wondering what they were

Comment: @Murphy: don't forget to go back through your questions and "accept" answers that have solved your problems.

Answer (score 0):

The hint here is that `2147483647` is MAX_INT.  You're hitting the upper limit.  You *could* try changing fitness2 to a long to confirm that's the problem, but I wouldn't recommend that as a fix.

I'd suggest using double, as that's what Math.sqrt is dealing with.

**Edit**: This isn't related to your question, but note that your calculation is going to be quite inaccurate as you get away from the equator.  The longitude lines bunch together, so you'll be exaggerating distance in the East-West direction.  One simple fix to that is to scale your x coordinate with the cosine of the average of the y coordinates. [Note: this assumes the Earth is a perfect sphere, which it's not, but it will get you pretty close]

**Edit 2**: E8, E9 etc mean `* 10 ^ 8`, `* 10 ^ 9` etc.  So 1.0E9 is 10 times bigger than 1.0E8.

Your coordinates are in microdegrees (1000000 per degree).  You might want to change your x1 x2 etc to doubles too, and divide the values by 1000000.

**Edit 3**: If you're not meaning to accumulate results, then you need to reset `distance2` between each iteration.  Try moving `double fitness2` *into* the outer loop.  That is,

```
ArrayList<Integer> yCoords = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (List<Integer> eachChromeNew : populationShuffle){
    double fitness2 = 0;
```

Comment: i have now updated the code which has given me a better set of results but still have one more error which can be seen above

Comment: sadly i still get the same results when moving the double fitness2 =0; the results keep increasing